# Probability of lightbulbs

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

There is a bank of four lightbulbs, each has a probability of 0.02 of being out when you flip the switch. The workingness of each lightbulb is independent of the others. Describe the state space of the bank of lightbulbs and list the probability of each state.

So I think the state space would be S={(on,off,off,off),(on,on,off,off),(on,on,on,off),(on,on,on,on)......} and there would be 16 of them, but since it says each one is independent of the others, I'm not sure if it is right.

Comment: Shouldn't independence just make it easier?

Comment: I'm just not sure will the independence affect the state space

Comment: The state **space** you choose is independent of independence. The **probabilities** that you assign to the various states will use the independence.

Comment: I don't get it, is the state space all the possibilities of lightbulbs combination?

Comment: Your are correct. The state space has the $16$ possibilities you identified.  Now you have to work out the probabilities.

Comment: you mean work out all 16 one by one? They won't all be the same or anything?

Answer (score 0):

The state space, or sample space is the collection of all possible results of the experiment. It is as you described it, {{on, on, on, on},....,..,{off, off, off, off}}. Like someone pointed out, the state space does not depend on the probability of any given outcome.

As to the probabilities, you can use these two main facts:

1)Since the bulb will be either on or off, P(off)= 1-P(on)

2) Since the outcomes are independent of each other, $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$.

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

The state-space is as you say, the probability is:

(Note $p = 0.02$)

So the probability that a light bulb is on is: $(1-p)$
The probability that a lightbulb is off is: $p$

Therefore, for each given state-space we have: $(1-p)^{numOn} \times  p^{numOff}$.

(Note: $s=0$ is {on,on,on,on} )

Ex: for your first state $P[s=0] = (1-p)^4\times p^0 = 0.922$